# What do I need to know about the dynamics of an industrial robot?

Tags: kinematics, inverse-kinematics, dynamics, industrial-robot, forward-kinematics

Apart from kinematics, what do i need to know about the dynamics and other things of a robot in order to calculate the angles of the joints for positions of the end effector exactly? that means: if i have a working model of a robot in matlab without considering masses and friction, will the end effector move according to the simulations in matlab?

Comment: You will have a poor model of a system without knowing most of the system dynamics. Masses, accel, dampening and etc are all required for the equations of motions.

Comment: Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, @morbo, so we try to keep them to a minimum. Partial answers, or answers you aren't confident about should still be posted as answers, since they can be improved by future edits. Comments should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post.